# Visual studio 2017 migrations

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-migrations

In Visual Studio 2017 I created a net core 2 web app. In package manager console I typed 
update-database

### and I received the following error

CREATE DATABASE [Potos.Travel.Web];

### System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access Denied) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\Users\grkouPotos.Travel.Web.mdf'.

I noticed that the file name 'C:\Users\grkouPotos.Travel.Web.mdf' should be 
'C:\Users\grkou\Potos.Travel.Web.mdf' there is a backslash missing. 
My USERPROFILE is c:\users\grkou
How can I fix this

Comment: What is your connection string?

Comment: "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=PotosTravelWeb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

Comment: I removed the dots from the db name

Comment: Seems like this is a bug in v14 https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/191393/localdb-v14-creates-wrong-path-for-mdf-files